# Need Help Regarding Menu Magement in admin

Tags: menus, wp-admin, admin-menu

We have a very big mega menu around 800 product categories with it, It working fine in frontend but having issue with backend menu manager. The page is not even opening and giving memory exhausted error. (increase the memory limit to 1 GB). Can anyone please suggest any plugin that will divide that big menu in chunks and made the menu management easy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should cache them, makes - however a alternate strategy, with much more effort for ne thinking and re-development, should much better. You can reduce the menu items with plugins, like Adminimize, but this have it also necessary to load initial bevor remove items in depends on the user role and also as admin for the settings page.

Comment: @bueltge  thanks but i think there is some confusion, i am taking about the front menu manager, i am using menu structure like amazon with around 800 categories and wordpress menu manager failed to hold that load, so looking for a efficient alternative. its a ecommerce site.

Comment: But this is the same topic, you should cache them in minimal or rethink. If you use the nav menu function from WP, you can use a cache plugin (https://github.com/inpsyde/menu-cache). The default of WP don't cache the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Check your PHP memory limit; memory should be **64MB** or above. 
you can try  increasing Memory  limit by  adding `define ('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');` in **wp-config.php** file.

Comment: I have already increased the memory limit to 1024M.